# How to handle a process in a pytest that must be run between 2 tests?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I am working on a test script using pytest and requests to do a series of tests regarding a new user flow. So inherently, the order of the tests matter since for example, I cannot login until I have created an account, etc. So far I am doing the following and it is working fine:

```
def test_create_user():
    blah

@pytest.mark.depends(on=['test_create_user'])
def test_login():
    blah
```

But in the next testcase I need to write, there is a dependency for me to 'process' something that is triggered only when the user logs in for the first time (which is not an actual test - so I should not def a new test for it). If that processing is not completed when I go to run the next testcase, the next testcase will naturally fail. Now, I have the requests POST written that will do handle this processing, but how should I implement it so that test3, say 'test_home_page', has a chance to run (and only after I complete the processing)?

```
def some_process_function():
     POST -> processed

def test_home_page():
    blah but I only run after some_process_function!
```

Thanks

Comment: Your tests are not isolated. You should delete the user created in `test_create_user` on test teardown and create a new user on `test_home_page` setup.

Comment: That is not an option unfortunately. I am OK with the tests not being isolated/independent. I am creating a test flow. If one test fails, the test will stop.

Comment: You can implement custom fixtures for preparing and cleaning up the test environment, see [pytest fixtures: explicit, modular, scalable](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html). However, you are trying to misuse unit tests to build some custom stuff, so expect your construct to remain fragile. Maybe it's wise to take a look at another testing concepts like BDD and use gherkin to define workflows/usecases. Hard to say without knowing more details of what you are doing.

Comment: a fixture worked -- thanks